# How to identify objects with broken reference properties in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, object, dereference

How do you correctly check for broken reference properties in google app engine?

Example:

```
class User (db.Model):
    userName = db.StringProperty(multiline=False)
class Foo (db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name="user_foo")
```

1. A User object was created.
2. A Foo object was created.
3. The corresponding reference property in User was then deleted.

Comment: This is not what "de-referenced" means.

Comment: Hi Nick, sorry, what's the correct terminology? a broken reference property? Thank you, A

Comment: De-referencing is what you do to get the object a reference points to. What you're talking about is a broken reference, or a dangling reference, or <insert terminology of choice here>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Daniel Roseman in the comments:

"iterate through all Foos and access item.user, and [check] if that ResolveError is raised"

```
from google.appengine.api import datastore_errors

all_foo = Foo.all()
for bar in all_foo:
    try:
        user_refProperty = bar.user
    except datastore_errors.Error, e:
        if e.args[0][0:40] == "ReferenceProperty failed to be resolved:":
            bar.delete()
            self.response.out.write('deleted due to bad reference property')
        else: raise
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just query on the `user` field:

```
referenced_users = Foo.all().filter('user', deleted_user_key)
```

Comment: and how would you determine the deleted_user_key without querying the Foo object?
Example: 
'all_foo = Foo.all()
for item in all_foo:
    deleted_user_key = item.user'

This will return "ReferencePropertyResolveError: ReferenceProperty failed to be resolved" i.e. is there another way to determine the deleted_user_key?

Comment: You don't, you get it from the User object that you deleted.

Comment: Ah, I see. The problem being, this is a "clean up an existing mess" type  script. The User object was deleted long ago and I'm trying to identify the Foo object(s) that were left de-referenced.

Comment: Then the only answer is to iterate through all Foos and access item.user, and if that ResolveError is raised then delete the Foo. There's no way of short-cutting this since AppEngine doesn't do JOINs.

Comment: This bug/issue suggest there is no way to test if a ReferenceProperty is still valid: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=426 i.e. you rely on the reference throwing an exception.